# Is it safe to call a (kotlin coroutine) withContext within another withContext?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have this simple code snippet:

```
fun setMapIcon(bitmapDescriptor: BitmapDescriptor?, 
               coordinateId:Long?, clickListener: (Double,Double) -> Unit ){
    
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
      
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
         //Do some heavy work that needs many variables
         withContext(Dispatchers.Main){ 
            //Publish variables
         }

         //Do more heavy work
         withContext(Dispatchers.Main){ 
            //Publish more variables
            //call `lambda` clickListener
         } 
      }  
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is totally normal and recommended way of using `withContext()` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are concerned about above code causing any issue then rest assured, the semantics are well defined and it will work as expected. As to if you should do it or not, [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-adv#main-safety) has following to say about it

```
suspend fun fetchDocs() {                      // Dispatchers.Main
    val result = get("developer.android.com")  // Dispatchers.Main
    show(result)                               // Dispatchers.Main
}

suspend fun get(url: String) =                 // Dispatchers.Main
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {              // Dispatchers.IO (main-safety block)
        /* perform network IO here */          // Dispatchers.IO (main-safety block)
    }                                          // Dispatchers.Main
}
```

> withContext() does not add extra overhead compared to an equivalent
> callback-based implementation. Furthermore, it's possible to optimize
> withContext() calls beyond an equivalent callback-based implementation
> in some situations. For example, if a function makes ten calls to a
> network, you can tell Kotlin to switch threads only once by using an
> outer withContext(). Then, even though the network library uses
> withContext() multiple times, it stays on the same dispatcher and
> avoids switching threads.